# Bash - MSBuild - File Logger

Tags: file, bash, logging, msbuild

I'm trying to improve our local build implementation, by using Bash and pending the success of a solution build, run the unit tests.

At the moment I want to pipe the results of the build in quite mode to the console (using default console logger) but pipe the results in more detail to a file using the file Logger.

From the bash I can execute the build fine, providing I don't specificy the FileLogger.

```
C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe /verbosity:q D:/MyDocs/Main.sln
```

The minute I do this :

```
C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe /verbosity:q D:/MyDocs/Main.sln /logger:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine; /flp:logfile=Build.Log
```

The build fails and I get a could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.

I've also tried changing dir so that I'm in the framework directory, but still get the same error.

As an aside I'm trying to provide the devs's with a quite verbosity for the local builds, but enable auto execution of the tests if the build is successful. I'll analyse build success by reviewing the contents of the Build.Log file for "Build Succeeded" Or "Build Failed"

I tried pushing the result to file using > "Build.log" but that impacts the colouring of the build output on the console which diminishes some of the value of what I'm trying to achieve.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)), when you say [bash](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/)?  Or are you running this under [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.aspx) is a namespace and not an [ILogger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.ilogger.aspx). If you replace that portion in:

```
/logger:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine;
```

... with a valid `ILogger` it's more likely to work.